# SQL to delete surplus rows where values are the same?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Week | Value1 | Value2 | Value3
-----|--------|--------|-------
1    | A      | A      | 5
1    | A      | B      | 10
1    | B      | B      | 15
2    | A      | A      | 10
2    | A      | B      | 15
2    | B      | B      | 20
2    | A      | A      | 10
2    | A      | B      | 15
2    | B      | B      | 25
```

I want to remove the surplus rows where Week, Value1, and Value2 match, but leave the original rows intact. So the desired result would look like this:

```
Week | Value1 | Value2 | Value3
-----|--------|--------|-------
1    | A      | A      | 5
1    | A      | B      | 10
1    | B      | B      | 15
2    | A      | A      | 10
2    | A      | B      | 15
2    | B      | B      | 20
```

I can select the data I need to remove using this code:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *, row_number() over(partition by week, value1, value2 order by week, value1, value2) as row
        from    mytable
        )
where   row >1
```

Does anyone know how best to go about actually removing these rows from the table please?

I'm on a db2 database, if that helps narrow down what functions do/don't work.

Comment: As you talk about 'surplus', how to you generate the source table? How is it populated? Depending on that, the solution might be different

Comment: How do you tell which row to keep and which to dismiss? There are two rows for week 2 B/B for instance and you keep the one with value3 = 20 and dismiss the one with value3 = 25. How do you get to that decision?

Comment: @Christophe An automated job runs each week to append that week's data to the table. The job also pulled in data from the equivalent week last year for year on year comparison, but since it has now been active for over a year it started pulling in weeks that were already in the table (this has now been rectified).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Where the rows have different figures for value3 the row with the lower value should be kept.

Comment: So in my opinion the change should take place in the automated job to ensure unicity, it will be more complicated to manage this afterwards

Comment: @Christophe The job has already been changed so there shouldn't be any more surplus rows coming in. I need a way to strip out the surplus rows that are already in the table though.

Comment: So @Gordon's solution is probably the best one (use a temporary table and change data in your table or create a new table that become the final one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, removing exact duplicates is tricky in many databases, and I think in DB2 as well.  One option is to add a new column that uniquely identifies each row.  Another is to recreate the table:

```
create temporary table temp_mytable as
    select distinct week, value1, value2
    from mytable;

truncate mytable;

insert into mytable (week, value1, value2)
    select week, value1, value2
    from temp_mytable;
```

If you had a unique id for each row, you would simply use:

```
delete from mytable
    where id <> (select min(t2.id)
                 from mytable t2
                 where t2.week = t.week and t2.value1 = t.value1 and t2.value2 = t.value2
                );
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified this a bit by creating a temp table with the data from mytable plus a column to flag the affected rows (using the row_number column from my original post), then truncated mytable and added in the data from the temp table where the flag was >1.

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete rows for which exists a sibling with a lower value3 (so as to only keep the row with the lowest value3).

```
delete from mytable
where exists
(
  select null
  from mytable better_row
  where better_row.week = mytable.week
  and better_row.value1 = mytable.value1
  and better_row.value2 = mytable.value2
  and better_row.value3 < mytable.value3
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It works on Db2 for LUW at least.

```
DELETE FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY WEEK, VALUE1, VALUE2 ORDER BY VALUE3) RN_ 
FROM MYTABLE
)
WHERE RN_ <> 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve a coding problem.  I work with iSeries DB2 and SQL and not familiar with DB2 on other platforms.  Since you have the SQL statement that correctly identifies the rows to be deleted another solution could be...

```
1.  Use an insert with the select statement that identifies the rows that are to be deleted and include RRN() in the select clause.
2.  Then perform the delete statement based on RRN.
```

This would cleanup the table but the better solution is prevent the duplicates at insert time as previously suggested.